# curl_exec is directly outputing data?

Tags: php, curl

I have this code

```
<?php
function get(){
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://stackoverflow.com/");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        $c = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        die("A");
        return $c;
}

$first = get();


?>
```

[but look what's output](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/3f901.php)! It just prints off everything returned from curl_exec();

how is that possible?

Comment: @downvoter: Can you at least say what is wrong with this question ?

Comment: The question is so simple, some think it hurts. See the answer.

Comment: Hey I'd recommend not printing out the stackoverflow page in an SO question.  It feels like phishing and confuses the shit out of ppl regardless :)

Comment: if you click to /login it throws you 404 so I think you/I don't have to worry about that ;)

Comment: however your're right. Added warning at the very top of that demo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes** (as you already have tested).

[`curl_exec` <sup>**PHP Manual**</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) does return output directly to the browser *unless* you make use of the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` constant [as documented](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php).

Comment: It does not make sense. There is "Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. " but there isn't "Outputs result on success or returns FALSE on failure. " However it works. Thanks

Comment: @genesis: it does make sense. turning on returntransfer makes curl_exec *RETURN* the fetched data, instead of directly outputting it.

Comment: @genesis: Looks like you have overseen it: 1.) **Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. However, if the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option is set, it will return the result on success, FALSE on failure.** - so read the whole text that is provided under **Return Values** - always. And 2.) next to that there is a code example below on that page that has a comment next to the `curl_exec` line that states: **grab URL and pass it to the browser**. So next tip is to read the examples.

Comment: yup, you're right. Why did you put this post to community wiki ?

Comment: Because the answer was so obvious that there's only one answer. If other folks want to contribute to it, that makes more sense than if everybody is answering nearly the same but on their own. And it protects me and others from downvotes on the answer, so some little precaution in this great browser game.

Comment: @hakre "the answer was so obvious", At first sight, curl_exec is expected to return the content fetched whereas it doesn't with the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option not set! IMO, the function should raise an exception on failure instead of returning FALSE.

Comment: @Stephan: Not all PHP extensions raise exceptions. in fact very little do. So whether or not an extension throws exceptions depends on which error handling an author of the extension opted for. One should not assume that PHP extensions throw exceptions unless it has been checked with the documentation or even better the source-code of the extension. Many functions return FALSE on error and then offer an additional function to obtain the error information.